# The Party at the End of the World #6 quest reward

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've looked up that you can either rescue the overseers son or leave him.

I presume when you rescue him he would come with a legendary outfit ( looked like he was wearing confessors robes).

What do you get if you leave him behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a legendary weapon: Miss Launcher (20-25)